# How to run DotNetKoans?

Tags: c#, .net

I have downloaded DotNetKoans from [github](https://github.com/CoryFoy/DotNetKoans) and successfully build the project but when I try to run them (follwing instructions and executing AutoKoanRunner.exe from cmd), I get following error:

```
KoanRunner.exe
  Building...
  Checking Koans...
  CSharp.AboutAsserts.AssertTruth has damaged your karma.

  The Master says:
        You have not yet reached enlightenment.

The answers you seek...

in AutoKoanRunner.Core.Master.WhereToSeek(String[] lines) Master.cs line 58
```

How can I run these Koans?

Comment: Maybe you should check that line.

Comment: I assume that the project is OK so I guess it's just some config or the environment.

Comment: The message says that something at that line is NOT OK, so maybe you should check  that out before making assumptions.

Comment: @RBarryYoung I did check the line but it is far from obvious what is going on inside the runner. In my experience this kind of things have simple solutions and you can generally find someone that had and resolved similar problem. Your suggestion is not really helpfull. Basically, you are saying: go and see it for yourself. Well, I can do that without the stackoverflow :)

Comment: Have you fixed any of the Koans yet? Which one have you got to before you get the error. It Works On My Machine (TM) for the first 10 or so...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, what I found is that Koans can only be run on English system because runner parses exception messages and searches literal "at" in error message.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone who still has problems running the DotNet koans: I forked the project and made the runner more robust. It should be independent of the language of the system, and it can be run in Visual Studio. I also made some corrections to the koans themselves.

You can find it at https://github.com/MarkVanPeteghem/DotNetKoans

Answer (score 0):

2022: I wasted some time trying to get the above 2 to work.

This one works: https://github.com/NotMyself/DotNetCoreKoans

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33004433)